# SQL order by Price / Sqm

Tags: php, sql

Quick question. I have a database of real estate, and the values Price and Floorsize, which is an integer of the property's square metreage. Normally I would order by price or floorsize, but this time I want to order by the price per sqm. Is there anyway I can do this in SQL. Maybe

```
SELECT * FROM Properties ORDER By (Price / Floorsize)
```

That is a guess. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Have you tried that? It seems ok.

Comment: why dont you try it first ?

Comment: Voting to close as not-a-real-question.

Comment: Sorry, I should have tried it first, you are right. It wasn't until I actually came to write it down in the question that it seemed as though it would work, by then I figured I might as well get the answer as I had written the question. Will help others no doubt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is right. It is the same way you posted in your question. Like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Properties ORDER BY (Price / Floorsize);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5bf16/1)

Comment: any difference between question and your answer ??

Comment: @NullPointer No, they are the same.

Comment: @NullPointer The OP was just guessing though it was the right guess :-)

Answer (score 3):

As Mahmoud answered the right solution, here is another one should You need to also select the price per sqm value:

```
SELECT *, (Price / Floorsize) ppsqm FROM Properties ORDER BY ppsqm;
```

Comment: I would have used yours, but the query is build from some conditionals which make it impractical. Thanks though